# Ubuntu as NAT Gateway with iptables

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, nat, gateway

I'm trying to configure Ubuntu 14.04 to act as a NAT gateway between a private and public network.

- Public Interface -> `eth0 (178.x.x.x)`
- Private Interface -> `eth0:0 (192.168.206.190/17)`

I've tried many combinations of `iptables` rules, but I can't get traffic to route out.  I have confirmed that the gateway can see the internet, and the hosts on the private network can see the gateway, and the default gateway is set correctly.

`net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` is set in `sysctl`.

My `iptables` rules are below.  My `iptables` experience is minimal, so it's quite possible I've missed something.

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Apr 21 12:38:44 2016
*security
:INPUT ACCEPT [215:14912]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [133:16208]
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Apr 21 12:38:44 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Apr 21 12:38:44 2016
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [215:14912]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [133:16208]
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Apr 21 12:38:44 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Apr 21 12:38:44 2016
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [3:132]
:INPUT ACCEPT [3:132]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Apr 21 12:38:44 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Apr 21 12:38:44 2016
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [215:14912]
:INPUT ACCEPT [215:14912]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [133:16208]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [133:16208]
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Apr 21 12:38:44 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Apr 21 12:38:44 2016
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [46:3296]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [28:3484]
-A FORWARD -i eth0:0 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth0:0 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Apr 21 12:38:44 2016
```

iptables -L -v

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 15 packets, 1044 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0:0 eth0    anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   eth0:0  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 10 packets, 1016 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Here is configuration of a host on the private network:

```
netstat -r
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         nat             0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
192.168.128.0   *               255.255.128.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

ping of 'nat' confirms host can see 'nat':

```
ping nat
PING nat (192.168.206.190) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from nat (192.168.206.190): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.359 ms
```

ping of 8.8.8.8 shows no traffic routing:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1999ms
```

Comment: You should only need to `MASQUERADE` in one direction, specifically for packets leaving the LAN and heading towards the WAN. There's no need for packets coming back from the WAN to be NATed to the gateway's IP. So try again without the `MASQUERADE` rule for `-o eth0:0`.

Comment: Thanks.  I have removed suggested line and applied, but still nothing is routing.  I have updated the iptables rules to reflect the current ruleset,  added the output of the current iptables -L -v if this helps.

Comment: How are you testing? At the outset, I would use simple `ping` tests to a host you know is up, rather than attempting to use higher level protocols (e.g. don't open a web browser yet). Try `ping <your favourite IP>` i.e. `ping 4.2.2.2` or similar. Your `iptables -L -v` dump shows no packets are being accepted in the `FORWARD` chain at all, which suggests nothing is reaching the box. Is the default gateway of your clients on the private LAN set to the IP of the Ubuntu box LAN interface?

Comment: I've added edits to show routing on private host, as well as testing.  As a side note, these hosts are on Linode, i don't know if their network routing / mac filtering is causing issues, i have a ticket in with them.

Comment: I've used tcpdump and concluded that no ICMP packages are making it to the 'nat' host when pinging 8.8.8.8.  So this looks to be either a routing issue on the private host, or a hypervisor/network level filter.

Comment: Yep, sounds like you need to talk to Linode in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provider (Linode) filters traffic by IP address at the hypervisor/network level, so traffic with public IP addresses will not transverse the private network at all.  I've changed provider now and NAT it working just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in this rule

```
-A FORWARD -i eth0:0 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

You have to change the position of the interfaces

```
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth0:0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Thanks, but that has not resolved the issue. but it may do once i fix the network level issue.  I'm waiting on Linode to confirm what sort of filtering is in place to stop the packets transversing the private network.